# jquery tooltip() php ajax request not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I got a html page #main that is fully loaded by a javascript function **loadNe()**. After the page gets fully loaded by the Ajax call, I want some tooltips to be shown when mouseovering some rows. Those tooltips makes Ajax requests to exhibit its content. The problem is:

The "open:" function inside tooltip() is probably never being executed because nothing gets printed in the console by the console.log() inside it. And also no network requests are sent to the tooltip's ajax URL. But still, the tooltip is working when I mouseover the elements, it shows me the title's tag content "Loading...".

What can be going wrong here?

```
function loadNe(ne){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/NOKIA/fx-load.php?label=" + ne,
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data){
                var content = fillResult(data);
                $("#main").html(content).hide();
                $("#main").fadeIn("slow");
                $(".sfp").tooltip({
                    track: true,
                    open: function (event, ui){
                        var sfp = $(this).text();
                        console.log("1-executing.."+sfp);
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "/NOKIA/sfp-load.php?sfp="+sfp,
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function(data){
                                console.log("2-executing.."+data["reach"]);
                                var html = "<tr><td>Alance: "+data["reach"]+"</td></tr>"+
                                           "<tr><td>Tamanho de onda: "+data["wavelength"]+"</td></tr>"+
                                           "<tr><td>Limiar Rx: "+data["rx_min"]+"</td></tr>";
                                $(".sfp").tooltip('option','content',html);
                            }
                        });                             
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was loading the bootstrap.min.js before the js-ui.min.js. The tooltip() function was executing the bootstrap library instead of the js-ui. So I inverted the order of loading as it is down here:

```
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```